# Javascript Trim left and right from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, trim

I am looking for an easy way to trim left side from my json response and trim right side from my json output.

An example my json how it is:

```
{"something":[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]}
```

How i want it to be:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]
```

As you can see I wat TrimLeft all before `[` and TrimRight alls behing `]` and this is where I have my json response in:

```
function responseHandler(res) { 
  return res; 
}
```

Comment: `return res.something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go would probably to just save this json to a variable and access the content of `something`  similar like this:

```
var jsonOutput = {"something":[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]};
var something = jsonOutput.something;
console.log(something);
```

The output should be the expected json.

### Edit 1

Referring to your edit I add another piece of code to come up to your solution.

```
function responseHandler(response) { 
    var result = response.something;
    return result ; 
}
```

This should give you the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to to that? You can access everything in that json respone. However you can just use javascript string functions, for example:

```
var x = '{"something":[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},
         {"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]}';

y = x.substr(x.indexOf("["),x.lastIndexOf("]")-x.indexOf("[")+1);

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj={"something":[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]};

var str=String(obj);
var output=str.substr(x.indexOf("["),x.lastIndexOf("]")-x.indexOf("[")+1);
JSON.parse(output);
```

> The String() function converts the value of an object to a string.
>
> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.
>
> The lastIndexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the last occurrence of the specified value, searching
>   backwards from fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.
>
> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally
>   transforming the value produced by parsing.

Comment: All this has been plagiarized from MDN. Nihar, you have to stop copy-pasting text from other web sites or answers. You can quote other sources, but you **must** make it clear that it's a quote (e.g. with quote formatting) *and* add a link back to where you took the quote.

Comment: sorry , I am new active member . That Won't happen again .

Answer (score 0):

if you your ({"something":) this content is fixed you can use below code.

```
<script>
var str = '{"something":[{"id":"1","name":"Test1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test3"}]}';
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1).replace('{"something":','');
console.log(str);
</script>
```